# Why does my script not produce output, when the same code in an interactive session does?

Tags: python

I got following from pycrypto example:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'o\x1aq_{P+\xd0\x07\xce\x89\xd1=M\x989'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
```

Now I create a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
message = "The answer is no"
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
ciphertext
#'o\x1aq_{P+\xd0\x07\xce\x89\xd1=M\x989'
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

When I run the script. I expect to see string output

```
'o\x1aq_{P+\xd0\x07\xce\x89\xd1=M\x989'
'The answer is no'
```

But I did not get anything. I tried `print ciphertext`, but it printed garbage.

Please help.

Comment: Your script is no REPL. You must `print` things.

Comment: Why would you expect it to print anything? There is no print statement in your script. If you print and it shows garbage, that's because your terminal is outputting the binary data in the ciphertext string.

Comment: Try `print obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scripts, just calling a variable doesn't print it like in an interactive shell. Try saving `obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)` as a variable and calling `print`, or just call `print` right before `obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
message = "The answer is no"
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
ciphertext
#'o\x1aq_{P+\xd0\x07\xce\x89\xd1=M\x989'
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
x = obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
print(x)
#or, just print obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Comment: thanks print(x) worked. but how to print ciphertext?

Comment: Just do `print(ciphertext)`

Comment: Also, accept the answer which best answered your question, since it has been 15 minutes and you have a multitude of very well written answers :)

Comment: how to print ciphertext?

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the `print` function (or `print` statement in py2) on what you want to print:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
message = "The answer is no"
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
print(ciphertext)
#'o\x1aq_{P+\xd0\x07\xce\x89\xd1=M\x989'
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key456', AES.MODE_ECB)
print(obj2.decrypt(ciphertext))
```

Comment: thanks print(ciphertext) still print out garbage. print(obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)) worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're running the script in non-interactive mode. That is, the example you saw there was someone running Python in the terminal or something similar.

Variables only print out in interactive mode when called alone.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a variable alone on a line doesn't print it out. You would need to use the print statement (or function, if in python 3) to do that.

You need to understand what a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is, and how this differs from a script.

In a REPL, you type a line, it is evaluated, and the resulting object is printed. In the case of python, the resulting object is *not* printed, if it evaluates to `None`, which is why only two lines in the example produced any output.

So, in your script, instead of:

```
obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Do:

```
print obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Or, if you want to get exactly the same output as the REPL, then do:

```
print repr(obj2.decrypt(ciphertext))
```

But it's unlikely that this is really what you want.